# how to separate two click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

i try to separate this two function. The first function is to **open a panel**, and the second function to **open show/hide object inside the panel**, but somehow when i click the show/hide button the panel close itself. click [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AH4zp/) to see the demo

---

**here is the javascript i used**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $("#dock li").click(function(){
            if($(this).find("ul").css("left") != "40px")    {
            $(this).find("ul").animate({left:"40px"}, 200); } else {
            $(this).find("ul").animate({left:"-370px"}, 200); } 
            });

            $(".slidingDiv").hide();
            $(".show_hide").show();

            $('.show_hide').click(function(){
            $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
            });

            $(".slidingDiv1").hide();
            $(".show_hide1").show();

            $('.show_hide1').click(function(){
            $(".slidingDiv1").slideToggle();
            });

        });
```

---

can anyone help me please?

Comment: this wont work. just use one function and add a condition to show or hide your element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second click function should be:

```
$('.show_hide1').click(function(event){
    $(".slidingDiv1").slideToggle();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

For more info see http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/